# how much will it cost me to exercise my HUT.WT.A

Tags: warrants

I have invested in HUT8 warrants over last 14 months I would like to exercise them to convert to shares in stock.
My HUT.WT.A are expiring June 15/2023.
My broker Questrade enquired with Hut8 investor relations department and advised me it would cost $6.25 per share of stock pre company merger with  (US Bitcoin).
Hut8 shares are trading at $2.  today How can they demand 3 times more than the current market trading price?
I have tried to communicate with Hut investor relations department leaving mutiple voicemail messages with no reply.
Can you help me to get answers, what can I do? what regulatory agency can I contact to make some sense of this situation.